# Use RTTIField.SetValue to set a Pointer to a Field

Tags: delphi, field, rtti

I have a Type:

```
TControlPointer = ^TControl;
```

And a private field in a class:

```
TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
  FPointer : TControlPointer;
end;
```

When a I try to set the value for FPointer using RTTI:

```
procedure SetControlPointer(pControl : TControlPointer);
[...]
RTTIField.SetValue(Self,pControl);
```

Compiler says 
[dcc32 Error] myunit.pas (xxx): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TValue' and 'TControlPointer'

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I can pass the TControl to the SetControlPointer(pControl : TControl) and SetValue(Self,@pControl). But I don´t know if passing a entire TControl is a good idea.

Comment: TControl (and every object) is pointer. Do you really need to use pointer to pointer?

Comment: @MBo You might if you wanted to modify a field in an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simply telling you that `RTTIField.SetValue` expects to be passed a `TValue`. So I guess you just need to put the pointer into a `TValue`

```
TValue.From<TControlPointer>(Self.pControl)
```

That's what you pass to `RTTIField.SetValue`.

You can probably let the compiler infer the type and simply write

```
TValue.From(Self.pControl)
```

Comment: It works! How to get back my TControlPointer from the RTTIField.GetValue(Self) ?

Comment: Use `AsType<TControlPointer>(...)` passing the `TValue`. `TValue` is fundamental with RTTI. You need to learn it.

Comment: TControlPointer.From<TValue>(RTTIField.GetValue(Self)) does not work.

Comment: Well no. That makes a new TValue.

Comment: I´ll search a little more about TValue. Thank you very much for now.

Comment: Yes! It´s my first question in stackoverflow. What should I do?